# SharePoint Online XML Field DateTime default on minute and NOT nearest half an hour

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, date-time, site-column, elements-xml

I have a Field (Site Column) element which is type DateTime

```
<Field DisplayName="Created" Name="Created" StaticName="Created" Type="DateTime" ID="{28C9A5E9-513C-415A-8C41-E7A3D767EABD}" Group="DateTime Columns">
    <Default>[today]</Default>
 </Field>
```

this deploys OK but what is happening is the default time is going to the nearest half an hour when you create a new record in the list

[image: Current happenings]

The date itself is fine, but I want the time to be the exact minute when the user clicks on "New" to create a new list record.

Most likely to do with the [today] default value, however, without a calculated field type, not sure what else will be accepted.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK I just found out that the field will only default to the nearest half an hour when the DateTime field is **editable**. So if you make the field hidden so the user will not be able to edit it, the row will be saved with the current time the save button was clicked

[image]

This doesn't actually answer my question directly but I now have the end result I wanted.